# How do I copy an object with presigned URL?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using a service that puts the data I need on S3 and gives me a list of presigned URLs to download (http://.s3.amazonaws.com/?`AWSAccessKeyID`=...&`Signature`=...&`Expires`=...).
I want to copy those files into my S3 bucket without having to download them and upload again.

I'm using the Ruby SDK (but willing to try something else if it works..) and couldn't write anything like this.

I was able to initialize the S3 object with my credentials (access_key and secret) that grants me access to **my** bucket, but how do I pass the "source-side" `access_key_id`, `signature` and `expires` parameters?

To make the problem a bit simpler - I can't even do a GET request to the object using the presigned parameters. (not with regular HTTP, I want to do it through the SDK API).

I found a lot of examples of how to create a presigned URL but nothing about how to authenticate using an already given parameters (I obviously don't have the `secret_key` of my data provider).

Thanks!

Comment: I doubt it. There is [AWS::S3::S3Object.copy_to](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/S3Object.html#copy_to-instance_method) but you'd need to get the web url as an S3:Object. I can't see how you can auth with a signature or inject a signature when getting an object. The best compromise would be to spin up an EC2 t2.micro instance in the same region and run the web download and API upload from there as the data transfer is free and relatively quick.

Comment: @mtm - I tried copy_to, it seems to work only when both buckets are in my account (no need to "double-authenticate"). I think it makes sense as a feature from AWS. Maybe it worth suggesting to them..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with a signed url, but as has been mentioned, if you fetch and upload within EC2 in an appropriate region for the buckets in question, there's essentially no additional cost.

Also worth noting, both buckets do not have to be in the same account, but the aws key that you use to make the request have to have permission to put the target object and get the source object.  Permissions can be granted across accounts... though in many cases, that's unlikely to be granted.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectCOPY.html

Comment: sadly, that's true.. I couldn't find a way to do it with SignedURL. Ended up with reading the file and writing it from EC2 machine in the same zone as the source bucket is.

Answer (score 2):

You actually can do a copy with a presigned URL.  To do this, you need to create a presigned PUT request that also includes a header like `x-amz-copy-source: /sourceBucket/sourceObject` in order to specify where you are copying from.  In addition, if you want the copied object to have new metadata, you will also need to add the header `x-amz-metadata-directive: REPLACE`.  See the [REST API documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectCOPY.html) for more details.

Comment: Could you give code example? How I'd use presigned url to copy to another bucket?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, even if this is not supported by the ruby sdk.