# Can you transfer a S3 file URL to a presigned S3 upload URL? Basically avoid download the file locally and uploading it to the presigned URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to transfer a s3 file from one account's bucket to another account's bucket and the only method is to use a presigned S3 upload URLs. The files I am looking to transfer are large (mp4 videos) so I would have to download it on my server first to a tmp folder then upload it to the presigned URL. Another thought I had was to send it to the browser and have it handled there but not sure if that is ideal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I copy an object with presigned URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24884593/how-do-i-copy-an-object-with-presigned-url)

Comment: A direct copy is not possible with presigned urls, you need to download and upload. Whether a (web) client would be faster in downloading and uploading would depend on that client's internet connection vs. your server's connection.